# Set JSX attribute based on another JSX attribute react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app, I have a `Card` component:

```
function Card({name, note, folder, tag}) {

    const typeHandler;

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={typeHandler} className="icon"/>
            <h3 className="text">{name}</h3>            
        </div>
    )
}
```

and I want the icon parameter to equal `folder` if when I call the card component, it has a `folder` JSX attribute, like this:

```
<Card name="Folder" folder/>,
```

and if its (instead of folder) `tag` then the icon will be `tag`, I have a few more of this if else if conditionals. How can I do that sort of thing?

The FontAwesomeIcon icon is just a string

I have tried that before:

```
function Card({name, note, folder, tag}) {

    const typeHandler = () => {
        if (note) {
            return 'sticky-note'
        }
        else if (folder) {
            return 'folder'
        }
        else if (tag) {
            return 'tag'
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={typeHandler} className="icon"/>
            <h3 className="text">{name}</h3>            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `icon={folder || tag}`

Comment: can't you do something like `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={folder !== undefined ? 'folder' : 'tag'} />` ? If you could clarify how you are calling Card and what is typehandler please, it will be easier

Comment: I can do that but I have more values

Comment: how to do import the folder and tag icons?

Comment: If you mean the font awesome icons: https://pastebin.com/9Adk2rvF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your parent component and pass an `icon` prop as a string with an icon name in lower case like:

**Parent component:**

```
<Card name="Folder" icon="folder" />,
```

and then update Card component like:

**Card component:**

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faFolder, faTag, faBars, faStickyNote } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
library.add(faFolder, faTag, faBars, faStickyNote)

export default function Card({ name, note, icon }) {
  const typeHandler = name => {
    switch (name) {
      case "folder":
        icon = faFolder; break;
      case "tag":
        icon = faTag; break;
      default:
        icon = faTag; break;
    }
    return { icon };
  };

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <FontAwesomeIcon {...typeHandler(icon)} className="icon" />
      <h3 className="text">{name}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[**Codesandbox Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-sun-lcfkg?file=/src/Card.js)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you will just pass on one of these fields to Card, You can use rest spread syntax simply pass on the icon default value incase nothing is passed

```
function Card({name, note, ...rest}) {


    return (
        <div className="card">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={rest[0] || 'defaultIcon'} className="icon"/>
            <h3 className="text">{name}</h3>            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary expressions for this, as long as you place them within curly braces. For example, if you want to set the icon parameter you could write something like:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={folder ? folder : “other-icon”} ... />
```

This is the equivalent of using a typical of-else statement to say: if folder is not null, set icon equal to folder, else set it equal to “other-icon”.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank, but can I use it with multiple if else statements?

Comment: @Roy You can but it's gonna be messy. Better externalize it in a function which will return the desired value.

Comment: You can use nested ternary expressions, which will work but give you a warning. For example icon={folder ? folder : <some_boolean/object> ? <value> : <other value>. This is the equivalent to having if, then else-if, then else.