# React JSX selectively pass attribute to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

This code works but I cannot help but think there's a better way of doing it. I cannot set expanded to false because the component breaks when I do (like they do in [Set JSX attribute based on another JSX attribute react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673331/set-jsx-attribute-based-on-another-jsx-attribute-react))

Also, I need to add more condition branches and it will mean duplication of code

```
if (itemProps.Expanded == true) {
  return (
    <Accordion expanded={true}>
    ...
    </Accordion >
  )
}
else {
  return (
    <Accordion>
    ...
    </ Accordion>
  )
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `<Accordion expanded={itemProps.Expanded == true}>`

Comment: What is the error coming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create props object dynamically and pass the props with ...(spread)

```
const props = itemProps.Expanded == true ? { expanded: true } : {};
return <Accordion {...props}>...</Accordion>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys tried this and it worked. Thank you for your time

````
let expanded = undefined;
if (itemProps.Expanded) {
  expanded = true;
}

return (
    <Accordion expanded={expanded}>
    ...
    </Accordion >
)
```
````

Comment: do this `expanded={itemProps.Expanded ? true : undefined}`